# Error : Insert Command error with Database as SQLITE

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite

I'm inserting data into SQLite using Python

database_tasks.bookId is a class variable

```
def insert(self, conn,dbname, name, writer='none'):
        c = conn.cursor()

        if dbname == "Book_database":            
            database_tasks.bookId += 1
            sql= "INSERT INTO Book_database VALUES(" + database_tasks.bookId + "," + name + "," + writer + ")"

        else:
            database_tasks.studentId += 1
            sql= "INSERT INTO Student VALUES("+ database_tasks.studentId + "," + name + ")"

        c.execute(sql)
        conn.commit()        
        return None
```

I'm getting an error with Insert command.

```
sql= "INSERT INTO Book_database VALUES(" + database_tasks.bookId + "," + name + "," + writer + ")"
```

> TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **never** build a query string including values to insert that way but used parameterized queries. It is an anti-pattern that has been used for decades to build SQL injection attacks. You should use:

```
    if dbname == "Book_database":            
        database_tasks.bookId += 1
        c.execute("INSERT INTO Book_database VALUES(?,?,?)",
                  (database_tasks.bookId, name, writer))

    else:
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

- it looks like your `bookId` is `int`. Cast it to `str` before combining.

```
sql= "INSERT INTO Book_database VALUES(" + str(database_tasks.bookId) + "," + name + "," + writer + ")"
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is fairly self explanatory - you are trying to concatenate an integer to a string.

my assumption is that database_tasks.studentId is an int, so changing your query to

```
sql= "INSERT INTO Book_database VALUES(" + str(database_tasks.bookId) + "," + name + "," + writer + ")"
```

would fix this, however be aware that if this is public facing, it would be very easy to exploit this, I'd recommend fully validating input, or changing your approach to this problem.